# Can't pass options for VLC Mozilla plugin from JS

Tags: javascript, firefox, vlc

I'm trying to pass some options for the VLC Mozilla plugin's embedded player, but nothing happens.

```
<embed
    type="application/x-vlc-plugin"
    id="vlc"
    width="400" height="300"
></embed>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var target = "http://example.com/videostream/";
    var options = new Array("--video-filter invert");

    vlc = document.getElementById("vlc");       
    var id = vlc.playlist.add(target,"Not Inverted Here",options);
    vlc.playlist.playItem(id);              
</script>
```

I've tried the same URL and args with command-line VLC, and it works.

```
vlc http://example.com/videostream/ --video-filter invert
```

(Anyway, I was trying various command line options with standalone VLC player, e.g. rotation, sepia, grayscale, blur, but I've failed. Maybe I have to enable or select something for VLC.)

The real problem is that I want to fix a video stream format error by passing `--demux=h264` to the embedded player (it works with desktop VLC player launched from command line), but first I want to pass *any* options to the embedded player, just to see that it works.

I'm using Ubuntu 15.04, Firefox 40.0 and VLC Web Plugin 2.2.0 (Weatherwax).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to force the demuxer selection it is easier than setting a filter.

From the help of vlc :

> Stream MRL syntax:
>   [[access][/demux]://]URL[#[title][:chapter][-[title][:chapter]]]    [:option=value ...]

Then you should be able to set the h264 demuxer using :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var target = "http/h264://example.com/videostream/";    
    vlc = document.getElementById("vlc");       
    var id = vlc.playlist.add(target);
    vlc.playlist.playItem(id);              
</script>
```

Comment: This URL protocol prefix looks exceptionally stupid, but **works**.

Answer (score 2):

In order to set options adding to the playlist you should use a syntax like :

```
var options = new Array(":video-filter=invert");
```

However this option is considered to be unsafe and you will get the following output (running firefox in foreground) :

> [00007f801e0fceb8] core input error: unsafe option "video-filter" has
>   been ignored for security reasons

In order to set this option you need to modify code in libvlc or VLC Web Plugin.

---

I tried to process video-filter option of the playlist as a trusted option without success. I think it needs to modify libvlc itself.

A way that I verified is to set the video-filter option as trusted in npapi-vlc.

To do this you can process like this :

1. Modify [npapi-vlc.git / npapi / vlcplugin_base.cpp](http://git.videolan.org/?p=npapi-vlc.git;a=blob;f=npapi/vlcplugin_base.cpp;h=bac810727ec4178ed556b342fed4ecabee7570ba;hb=HEAD) processing a new option `extra`

   ```
   NPError VlcPluginBase::init(int argc, char* const argn[], char* const argv[])
   {
       ....
       /* parse plugin arguments */
       for( int i = 0; (i < argc) && (ppsz_argc < MAX_PARAMS); i++ )
       {
           ...
           else if( !strcmp( argn[i], "extra" ) )
           {
               ppsz_argv[ppsz_argc++] =  argv[i];  
           }
           ...
       }
   ```

   Build and install the modified npapi-vlc plugin.
2. Modify the html to set this new option :

   ```
   <embed type="application/x-vlc-plugin" id="vlc" width="400" height="300" 
   extra="--video-filter=invert" />
   ```

Like this you could set, I guess, any option of the command line, removing the safe option check.